# Animate in riot.js to fade in after re-render

Tags: riot.js

Can anyone point me at an example of using riot.js with jQuery animations?

I'd like to tap into the event after riot re-renders something, and then fire  jQuery `$(selector).fadeIn()` on the element that has changed.  The problem is that, the element may not exist yet when I'm changing the data, so I can't run the jQuery fadeIn until after Riot finishes re-rendering.

The best I can come up with is `setTimeout`; is there an event in Riot that I can listen to directly?

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/riot/animore ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Riot has two events for re-rendering:

- update - this is before rendering
- updated - after rendering has happened

  this.on(
      'update',
      function () {
      }
  )

One another possibility, is to learn about MutationObserver.
See http://davidwalsh.name/demo/detect-node-insertion.php

The riot events only tells you that something has been updated or is about to update, but not what parts of the dom will change.

Comment: Riot's updated event is the closest to what I want, but the problem is it will fire when anything within the tag changes and I want something that can isolate updates to individual sections without having to slice up something into one-off single-use components.

Comment: @wrschneider - wouldn't a sub-component do it for you?